# React + Redux: How to update state when store is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Sorry for the noob question, but trying to learn React + Redux and the book I'm using has some overview stuff, but no directions on "tying it all together".

Take a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chapt8-redux-store?file=index.js

You'll see that I have an initial state of colors, with a couple of reducers and action creators.

My question is basically, **How do I update controls/state when my store is updated?**

Looking at line 49, I set the initial state from the store; then, on rows 51 through 54, I subscribe to the store changes where I call `this.setState` and get the new state of my store.  Also on row 71, i'm setting the `colors` constant by assigning it to state.

**Is this the best/right way? Or, is there a better way? Is is best to update state which, in turn, updates the colors (like I'm currently doing)?  Or, should I be updating the colors somehow via the `subscribe` function?**

Thanks for insight/direction.

Comment: this is not how it is done, store should be created outside of your component. and then you either use the Provider component, or use the connect api to bind the redux state to your component, then you do the state change by dispatching action creators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way you have this works, but typically whatever you pull out of the store does not go into the `state` of your component - the point of the store is to avoid keeping that state in the first place.

So the next step would be to add `react-redux` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) as a dependency and use the `connect` function to pull the state out of the store and feed it to the component via props:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
    ... code for <App/> component
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    ... code to pick out only the relevant state from the props
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I highly recommend Stephen Grider's videos on udemy, it covers some of this stuff specifically and it's really too much to put into a post here

Comment: your first paragraph is what I _assumed_ (I felt my current way was like going through the hand to get to your elbow), but I wanted to make sure.   thanks.